# Extract emails from the entered values in python

Tags: python, loops

My objective is: I need to ask the user to enter the number of emails and then initiate a for loop to register the input email. Then, the emails will be segregated based on '@professor.com' and '@student.com'. This will be counted as appended in the list. Following is what I have tried

```
email_count = int(input('how many emails you want'))
student_email_count = 0
professor_email_count = 0
student_email = '@student.com'
professor_email = '@professor.com'

for i in range(email_count):
   email_list = str(input('Enter the emails')
   if email_list.index(student_email):
       student_email_count = student_email_count + 1
   elif email_list.index(professor_email):
       professor_email_count = professor_email_count + 1
```

Can someone help to shorten this and write it professional with explanations for further reference? Here, the appending part is missing. Could someone through some light there too ?

Thanks

Comment: if you create a list and then use its `.append` method that'll do the appending... Have you tried running your code as is though and entering a mix of emails - you've got another error that's going to crop up...

Comment: Are the emails entered one at a time? or multiple emails separated by what, space?

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for the feedback. I have noticed that only finding the '@professor' index works. However, the '@student' index doesnt work. It gives an error stating that value error-substring not found. Why is that. Could you please, rewrite the code, may be more efficiently, if possible

Comment: Vinny: No, the code run through the loop. First iteration, it asks for the input and then next iteration it asks for the next input. So, emails are entered one at a time with each iteration. However, as I indicated earlier, there is a value error when entering @student.com

Comment: What error do you get? Are you on Python 3 or 2.7?

Comment: I am okay with the code that you posted. However, is there a simpler way of achieving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prof_email_count, student_email_count = 0, 0

for i in range(int(input("Email count # "))):
    email = input("Email %s # " % (i+1)) 

    if email.endswith("@student.com"):  # str.endswith(s) checks whether `str` ends with s, returns boolean
        student_email_count += 1
    elif email.endswith("@professor.com"):
        prof_email_count += 1
```

Is what a (somewhat) shortened rendition of your code would look like. Main differences is that I'm using `str.endswith(...)` over `str.index(...)`, also that I've removed the `email_count`, `student_email` and `professor_email` variables which didn't seem to be used anywhere else in the context.

EDIT:

To answer your comment on  scalability, you could implement a system such as this:

```
domains = {
    "student.com": 0,
    "professor.com": 0,
    "assistant.com": 0
}

for i in range(int(input("Email count # "))):
    email = input("Email %s # " % (i+1))

    try:
        domain = email.split('@')[1]
    except IndexError:
        print("No/invalid domain passed")
        continue

    if domain not in domains:
        print("Domain: %s, invalid." % domain)
        continue

    domains[domain] += 1
```

Which allows for further scalability as you can add more domains to the `domains` dictionary, and access the count per `domains[<domain>]`

Comment: Thank you for the code. It is a short version of course. Can I ask, if it is possible to treat the domain as a list or a dictionary to scan it through the loop and segregate the values. Like, emails = ['@student.com', '@professor.com', '@assistant.com' ] or {'student' : '@student.com', 'professor': '@professor.com', 'assistant' : '@assistant.com'}; then run this this through the loop.

Comment: @jeff Edited answer to suffice your request

Answer (score 1):

It seems your iteration accepts one email at a time; and executes `email_count` times. You can use this simple code to count students and professors:

```
st = '@student.com'
prof = '@professor.com'

for i in range(email_count):
    email = str(input('Enter the email'))
    if st in email:
        student_email_count += 1
    elif prof in email:
        professor_email_count += 1
    else:
        print('invalid email domain')
```

**If you are using Python 2.7, you should change input to raw_input**.

---

Here's a scalable version for your code, using `defaultdict` to support unlimited domains.

```
email_count = int(input('how many emails you want'))
student_email_count = 0
professor_email_count = 0

from collections import defaultdict
domains = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(email_count):
    email = str(raw_input('Enter the email\n'))
    try:
        email_part = email.split('@')[1]
    except IndexError:
        print('invalid email syntax')
    else:
        domains[email_part] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. You code, is working. However, is this the best way to write this ?

Comment: If you only have two domains and short list of emails, then it's a decent way. It is short, readable, and easy to understand. However, this code is not scalable. Once you need to add more domains, you should define it differently.

Comment: You're suggesting that the code is based off Python 3, yet a `SyntaxError` would be raised on the last line as you require parantheses to call functions.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. I'm using python 2.7, I forgot updating it when posting

Comment: @jeff I've updated the answer with a scalable version; imo this is the way to implement your solution.